# Trouble importing org.apache.commons.lang on JSP page

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, package

I'm having trouble importing the org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils which gives me the error: **The import org.apache.commons.lang cannot be resolved** I know this question has been posted a number of times but i tried them and it didnt solve my problem.

[image]

Things i did were:

- Download the packages and add them to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder
- Imported but it still showed me the error
- Restarted server
- Cleaned project several times
- Closed eclipse and back on

Nothing solved my problem. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using version 3 of Apache Commons Lang. The correct import is:

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils
```

Note the *lang3* part of the path

Comment: Ah.. what a miss! Thank you! Solved in a second :-)